# Why is my argument capitalized in python when I didn't specify too?

Tags: python, argparse

Why does Python capitalize object in add_argument on argparse?

This code prints FOO which is Capitalize in the terminal

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', help='foo help')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Here are the results in my terminal when running the program of which I don't understand

```
usage: myprogram.py [-h] [--foo FOO]

options:
-h, --help  show this help message and exit
 --foo FOO   foo help
```

So why does this happen when I do not specify in the terminal?

I wasn't expecting the repel in python to capitalize the 'foo' to 'FOO'

```
usage: myprogram.py [-h] [--foo FOO]
```

Comment: That's just its built-in documentation convention. Uppercase names are used to represent values that the user is supposed to fill in, while lowercase is used for literals.

Comment: If you want a different name, use the `metavar=` in the `add_argument()`.  It's just a place holder.

Comment: You asked for the help didn't you?  The argparse docs shows the style of help display.